# Populate dropdown list in Datagrid on Dropdown Selection Changed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I am working with a Datagrid in an ASP.Net Webforms Application. The Datagrid has two dropdown lists within it as per the code here

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tab table table-bordered table-striped table-hover " ID="dgUnsuitableSwitch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Fund Name" HeaderText="Fund Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Fund Risk Profile" HeaderText="Fund Risk Profile" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Investment Date" HeaderText="Investment Date" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Product" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="centre" ID="ddlProduct">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Fund" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="centre" ID="ddlFund">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Amount (£)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Amount" Width="50px" ID="txtOtherExistingAmount"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtOtherExistingAmount1" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtOtherExistingAmount" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars=".-0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Lump Sum Amount (£)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="50px" placeholder="Amount" ID="txtLumpSumAmount"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtLumpSumAmount1" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtLumpSumAmount" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars=".-0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

</Columns>
```

I am able to populate the first dropdown list without issue,  like so

```
For Each item As DataGridItem In dgUnsuitableSwitch.Items
 Dim ddlProduct As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlProduct"), DropDownList)

 With ddlProduct
     .Items.Add("-- Select Product --
     .Items.Add("Premium")
     .Items.Add("Growth")
     .Items.Add("Income")
     .Items.Add("Index"
     .Items.Add("Fixed ")
     .Items.Add("Cash")
 End With
```

Next

The problem I am having is to bind the change event to the dropdown list but am unable to get it to work right now.

I believe I need to ad an event handler but not sure where I would need to add this, Or could be completely wrong.

I am happy for answers in either VB or C#

thanks

Simon

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as catching the SelectedIndexChanged event that fires off when you change the index of the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this JQuery

```
$(".ddlMoveToProduct").change(function() {
            var fundId = $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').attr("id");

            console.log(fundId);

            var option = $(this).val();
            var params = {
                val: option
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SelectMoveToFund",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('select').select2('destroy');
                    var ddl = $("#" + fundId);

                    ddl.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                    $.each(data.d, function () {
                        ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                    $('select').select2();

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error :" + data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
```

then using a webmethod

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), _
System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SelectMoveToFund(val As String) As List(Of ListItem)
    '' will be changing this to an ajax call 

    Dim dt = GetFundsToMoveTo(val)

    Dim retVal = (From row As Object In dt.Rows Select New ListItem() With {
        .Value = row(0),
    .Text = row(0)}).ToList()

    Return retVal

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume something like this would solve it?

We usually use Telerik radgrids, so I'm not very familiar with gridviews, but I can't think that it would be very different.

Basically you first bind your datasource to your grid with a default value (if you want / need) then whenever the index changes of your ddl you call the same function that set up the datasource the first time with the value of you index.

Then use that value to filter or gather a new datasource.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
        'Bind your grid
        BindGrid() 
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Print any exceptions to your validator
        'Me.CustomValidatorAdditional.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        'Me.CustomValidatorAdditional.IsValid = False
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid(Optional ByVal Product As String = "premium")
    Try
        dgUnsuitableSwitch.DataSource = GetProducts(Product) 'returns a datasource 
        dgUnsuitableSwitch.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.CustomValidatorAdditional.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Me.CustomValidatorAdditional.IsValid = False

    End Try
End Sub

protected void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
' Set your new datasource / filter on your old. 
' I use Telerik, but it would looks something like this
    bindGrid(e.Value) 'Change the parameter to your choice. 
}
```

If you only need to change the content of another ddl depending on what your main ddl's index is, then you do it similarly to how I did it there, but instead of binding the grid with a datasource you bind the ddl with a set of items of your choice that changes depending on a condition:

```
Private Sub changeDdl(Optional ByVal Product As String = "premium")
    Dim ddlFund As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlFund"), DropDownList)

    IF (Product = "premium)
       ddlFund.items.add(item) 'Or however the syntax is for a asp-ddl list
                               ' And this continues until you have set your items

   ELSE IF (Product = "Growth")
        ddlFund.items.add(item) 'Or however the syntax is for a asp-ddl list
                                ' And this continues until you have set your items

    'etc etc etc'
End Sub
```

Comment: that's very similar to what I had already tried, but unfortunately im not getting it hit the changed event using this code. 

I have however changed tac, and think I have found a solution using JQuery

Comment: May I suggest that you attempt to specifically ensure that the the ASP-> Code behind works before using any third party stuff?
Specifically add this to your dropdown:
<asp:dropdownlist OnSelectedIndexChanged="changeDdl">